# Slow booting ASP.NET Application

Tags: asp.net, iis-10

I am having problems with an ASP.NET application loading in slowly. The site runs under IIS but seems to sit for about 2 minutes just trying to call the StartApplication method:

[image]

The CPU and disks don't seem to have any problems and other sites are loading normally.

I have tried clearing the temporary internet files to see if was a problem with the cache.

Any ideas or suggestion on how I can diagnose this problem?

Comment: Please check `Web Server (IIS)` in Event Viewer for any errors

Comment: Check SQL Server profiler for query run.. May be worth creating new site in IIS with different app domain.. Try loading empty hello world aspx page, or just text file, may be it’s only the homepage, try child pages.. Checkout raw headers in fiddler..

Comment: `System.Web` was designed without much performance in mind. If possible, switch to ASP.NET Core. If you cannot easily migrate, such cannot be diagnosed easily without hang dump analysis.